# Three (in)correct statements about velocity of a vector function

Tags: calculus

I would love to get some feedback to know whether the following line of reasoning is correct:

Within time-span $t \ge 0$ a particle is located on the curve $\mathbf c (t) = 3 \cos(2πt)\mathbf i +3\sin(2πt)\mathbf j+5t\mathbf k$. Which amongst the following statements is correct?

1. The velocity vector is constant.
2. The speed/velocity of the vector is constant.
3. In order to get to a height of 5 units above the plane, the particle needs to pass approximately 19.5 units of length.

I reasoned this as follows:

1. is incorrect. To asses velocity, one needs to study the derivative(s) of the location vector: these come out as -6πsin(2πt),6πcon(2πt) and 5 respectively, where only the velocity along the z-axis is constant.
2. is correct. The norm of the three velocity vectors given under 1) comes out as $\sqrt {36π^2+25}$(units per second), which is constant.
3. according to the original formula it takes 1 second to get to 5 units of height, and therefore $\sqrt {36π^2+25}$ units per second times 1 second is $\sqrt {36π^2+25}$units, which is roughly 19.5 units.

Comment: looks good to me

Answer (score 1):

That looks good to me. The only thing I can even quibble at is your typo "con"($2\pi t$).